# Configure Qt Creator to build statically (Ubuntu)

Tags: qt, ubuntu, static

I'm trying to build a static application on Ubuntu (if it matters, Ubuntu running in a virtual machine in Windows), [following the Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/linux-deployment.html). Accordingly, I have build the libraries from source, using the configuration from the documentation:

```
./configure -static -prefix /path/to/Qt
```

There were no error messages from the build from source. I have tried setting the PATH variable in the build environment to the directory that contains my static build files. I've also tried specifying this path in the .pro file's LIBPATH variable. Nevertheless, whenever I build the application, a call to ldd shows that there are still dependencies to the Qt's dynamic libraries. I'm at a loss to understand how I need to configure Qt Creator to fix this.

Comment: You need static build of Qt libraries to build your app statically

Comment: I did do that. I've edited the question to make that clearer.

Comment: You maybe compile your project with another non static Qt version. Do you have other Qt versions except your static build? If yes, you just have to add your static build - `Tools/Options/Build and Run/Qt versions/Add` and construct your kit with this version - `Tools/Options/Build and Run/Kit`. When you have your kit you can compile the project - Projects(left panel)/Build and run/Add kit

Comment: I've removed other other Qt installations, and rebuilt the static libraries. Working from the command line (to begin with), I get errors about missing files (uic), that I can resolve by installing qttools5-dev-tools. Yet the executable then has Qt dependencies. I assume dynamic dependencies are creeping in through qttools5-dev-tools; what is the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You should download sources of interested Qt version, configure for static build and compile them yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I did do that already. I've edited my question to make it clearer.